# FCM notification isn't showing even when data is being received from server

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to receive notification data in my `FirebaseMessagingService` like this:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    String notificationTitle = null, notificationBody = null, url = null;
    remoteMessage.getData();
    Object obj = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
    Object obj1 = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
    Object obj2 = remoteMessage.getData().get("click_action");
    notificationTitle = String.valueOf(obj);
    notificationBody = String.valueOf(obj1);
    url = String.valueOf(obj2);
    Log.d("notification",notificationTitle+" "+notificationBody+" "+url); //this shows the correct data
    sendLocalNotification(notificationTitle, notificationBody, url);
}

private void sendLocalNotification(String notificationTitle, String notificationBody, String url) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;
    if(url == null || url.length() == 0) { //when user taps the notification then it should open the app by default
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, record_viewer.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                .setContentText(notificationBody)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri);
    }
    else{ //when user taps the notification then it should redirect to the url
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));

        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.download_icon)
                .setContentIntent(pending)
                .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                .setContentText(notificationBody)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri);
    }

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(1234, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

I am sending the notification payload using `cURL` method in my `PHP` :

```
$notifData = [
        'title' => "Hey, ".$_POST["employee"],
        'body' => $body,
        'click_action' => "URL HERE"
];
$apiBody = [
        'data' => $notifData,
        'time_to_live' => 2000, 
        'to' => $deviceToken
];
                        
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($apiBody));
```

The `click_action` is optional here. When I pass the URL then the user should be able to redirect to the url site on tapping the notification,  otherwise it should just open the app.

But the problem is that, the notification never shows, irrespective of the app being in foreground or background. Why is that? How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you're like me and were recently tripped up by this, it's likely a permission issue. Would you check the app permissions to see if the notification permission is enabled?

[Notification runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission) were added in the latest Android release.